# Delete Local References Not Starting With Match

Tags: regex, git

The strategy that we have for the project I'm working on is to release the project in phases, aka releases. Therefore our branching strategy is to have `release1` act as the master branch for all features related to the first release, `release2` for the second, and so on.

Occasionally I like to clean out the local instances of my branches. The majority of the time they've either been merged into their respective release branch or they've been abandoned. This usually involves the following sequence:

```git
$ git branch
--- prints the list ---
$ git branch -d branch1, branch2, branch3, etc...
```

To try and do this in one go I tried running the following command:

```git
$ git branch | grep -v '^release.+|QA' | xargs git branch -d
```

The idea is that it should:

1. Get every branch
2. Grep everything that does not start with `release` and is also not `QA`
3. Pass the branches to the `git branch -d`

But what is happening is that it is delete every branch except for the branch I currently have checked out. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find that `git branch` output is intended to be read by humans, but has some quirks (there is a `*` in its output to mark the active branch, each line starts with two spaces ...) that make for a poor scripting experience.

Try using `git for-each-ref` instead :

```
# here is the mantra to get all local branch names :
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads | grep -v ...
```

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect. I modified my pattern a little bit to account for the pipe character and this is what I ultimately wound up using (and will continue to use going forward): `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads | grep -v 'release.*\|QA' | xargs git branch -d`

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind it is quite simple.

```
git branch
```

```
  QA
* master
  not-release1
  not-release2
  not-release3
  release1
  release2
  release3
  release4
```

Each line begins with 2 spaces. So that's why your regex is not matching. Secondly, there is an asterisk.

---

The asterisk would only give a minor error like `error: branch '*' not found.` whereas your current checked branch can't be deleted according to git. Since nothing was matching your regex, the option `-v` inverted that and every branch matched, deleting everything except your current branch.

`error: Cannot delete branch 'master' checked out at ...`

---

Solution to your problem

```sh
git branch | grep -v "^ *release" | grep -v "QA" | xargs git branch -d
```